# Why does react hooks not support purecomponent or shouldComponentUpdate function？

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I want to realize the multi-selection function of flatlist. I directly changed the example on the official website. The official website address is: [https:/reactnative.cn/docs/flatlist](http://https:/reactnative.cn/docs/flatlist). Because there are many items in the list, I want to use shouldComponentUpdate to prevent over-rendering of items. But I found that react hooks writing method can not achieve multi-selection, it can not save the selected state, but the class writing method can achieve multi-selection, what is the reason? The source code of FlatList Item is as follows,

```
    import {StyleSheet, Text, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class Item extends Component {
    shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
        return this.props.selected !== nextProps.selected;

    }

    render() {
        const {title, onSelect, selected, id} = this.props;
        console.log(title + ' is render');
        return (
            <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={() => onSelect(id)}
                style={[
                    styles.item,
                    {backgroundColor: selected ? '#6e3b6e' : '#f9c2ff'},
                ]}
            >
                <Text style={styles.title}>{title}</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        marginTop: 40,
    },
    item: {
        backgroundColor: '#f9c2ff',
        padding: 20,
        marginVertical: 8,
        marginHorizontal: 16,
    },
    title: {
        fontSize: 32,
    },
});
export default Item;
```

the App source code of class writing is as follows,

```
    import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {
    View,
    FlatList,
    StyleSheet,
} from 'react-native';
import Item from '../component/Item';

const DATA = [
    {
        id: 'bd7acbea-c1b1-46c2-aed5-3ad53abb28ba',
        title: 'First Item',
    },
    {
        id: '3ac68afc-c605-48d3-a4f8-fbd91aa97f63',
        title: 'Second Item',
    },
    {
        id: '58694a0f-3da1-471f-bd96-145571e29d72',
        title: 'Third Item',
    },
];

class App extends Component {
    state = {
        selected: new Map(),
    };
    onSelect = (id) => {
        const newSelected = new Map(this.state.selected);
        newSelected.set(id, !this.state.selected.get(id));
        this.setState({
            selected: newSelected,
        });
    };

    renderItem = ({item}) => (
        <Item
            id={item.id}
            title={item.title}
            selected={this.state.selected.get(item.id)}
            onSelect={this.onSelect}
        />
    );

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <FlatList
                    data={DATA}
                    renderItem={this.renderItem}
                    keyExtractor={item => item.id}
                />
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        marginTop: 40,
    },
    item: {
        backgroundColor: '#f9c2ff',
        padding: 20,
        marginVertical: 8,
        marginHorizontal: 16,
    },
    title: {
        fontSize: 32,
    },
});

export default App;
```

the App source code of hooks is as follows.

```
 import React, {Component, useState} from 'react';
import {
    View,
    FlatList,
    StyleSheet,
} from 'react-native';
import Item from '../component/Item';

const DATA = [
    {
        id: 'bd7acbea-c1b1-46c2-aed5-3ad53abb28ba',
        title: 'First Item',
    },
    {
        id: '3ac68afc-c605-48d3-a4f8-fbd91aa97f63',
        title: 'Second Item',
    },
    {
        id: '58694a0f-3da1-471f-bd96-145571e29d72',
        title: 'Third Item',
    },
];
const App = () => {
    const [selected, setSelected] = useState(new Map());
    const onSelect = (id) => {
        const newSelected = new Map(selected);
        newSelected.set(id, !selected.get(id));
        setSelected(newSelected);
    };

    const renderItem = ({item}) => (
        <Item
            id={item.id}
            title={item.title}
            selected={selected.get(item.id)}
            onSelect={onSelect}
        />
    );
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <FlatList
                data={DATA}
                renderItem={renderItem}
                keyExtractor={item => item.id}
            />
        </View>
    );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        marginTop: 40,
    },
    item: {
        backgroundColor: '#f9c2ff',
        padding: 20,
        marginVertical: 8,
        marginHorizontal: 16,
    },
    title: {
        fontSize: 32,
    },
});

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

React.memo is for shouldComponentUpdate.
Here is an official doc:
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-do-i-implement-shouldcomponentupdate

Answer (score 0):

Read about [VritualizedList](https://reactnative.dev/docs/virtualizedlist) which FlatList extends

> Internal state is not preserved when content scrolls out of the render window. Make sure all your data is captured in the item data or external stores like Flux, Redux, or Relay.

In short, trying to optimize FlatList items with shouldComponentUpdate or React.memo is mostly pointless - items don't preserve their state, and are remounted on renders. Even if you were using class components with shouldComponentUpdate it wouldn't help, as every render your components are destroyed and re-created. FlatList already optimizes performance for you by only rendering a limited amount of items instead of rendering entire list at once

Comment: You answered well, but can you run down the example? The FlatList in the example has only three items, and the state of the item is saved in the App

Comment: Flatlist is a PureComponent. in short, add extraData={selected} to your Flatlist @jianfeiwu